# Google Form Confirmation Page with a Button to Create a Report, via Browser Access

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have created a Google Form. From the Confirmation page I would like to create a button that says "See Test Score". At that point I want to create a report of sorts, accessible via a browser, using apps script. The report would access data from a Google Spreadsheet via apps script. I just need to figure out a way to create the report. The report data will mostly be in table format but I may want to add a graph or two. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this using a Google Form. However, what you can do is write a UI using Google Apps Script which has the same fields as your form. You can customize this UI a lot more where you can show a report on the confirmation screen etc.

I suggest you go through the Google Apps Script tutorials and start writing your UI. If you get stuck or need help, come back with the issue you're facing